# ECIES is must with Symmetric?(ECIES-AES or ECIES-TDES)

Tags: ecies

I can't understand the ECIES algorithm.

I saw two different ECIES algorithms:

1. Using only Public key

   **Key generation:**

   $A_{pri} : n_A$
   $A_{pub} : n_A G$

   $B_{pri} : n_B$
   $B_{pub} : n_B G$

   **Encryption:**

   Select a random $k$.

   A -> B to Cipher C : $\{kG, \text{message} + k B_{pub}\}$

   **Decryption**

   $\text{message} + k B_{pub} - n_B kG = message + k n_B G - n_B k G = \text{message}$
2. Using Symmetric key(AES)

what is real?

Comment: The first one looks like [ElGamal encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption) and not like ECIES to me.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the above algorithm is ECIES?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ECIES is essentially a *more practical* implementation of ElGamal, a hybrid cryptosystem.  It uses symmetric encryption following an ephemeral key exchange.

Refer to : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme

Compare it with : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption

The only difference is that instead of using KDF+XOR or AES+GCM as the symmetric cipher, ElGamal specifies a different symmetric step mapping the message to a point and using inverse modulo to recover.

Once of the oddities is that using a KDF and then using XOR was the most popular version of ECIES for a number of years.   If used carefully, it's OK, but without properly padding the message, things can get ugly (chosen ciphertext attacks, etc.)

Ditching XOR and using AES/GCM with the shared secret seems, to me, like the better move, shifting responsibility for the authentication onto the symmetric layer.  The use of KDF/XOR is still prevalent in modern libraries, mostly because some XOR variants were FIPS certified.

Comment: Please explain, or at least quote, the substantive parts of the links you cite.  Links may change and don't help a reader on this site.

Comment: ECIES is _not_ an instance of or implementation of Elgamal encryption.  Elgamal encryption encrypts a _point on the curve_; ECIES encrypts a _bit string_ under a symmetric-key cipher with a key derived from a public-key key agreement.  They are not related except in that they use a group in which discrete logs are hard.